# Java Commons.net & FTP Permissions

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I regularly upload files to a particular RedHat 5.5 Server with no problems using FileZilla.

I am now trying to FTP to the same server with the Java Library *org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient* while using the exact same credentials (un, pw, and ip address). I keep getting an error `Connection Refused: Connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(NativeMethod) at...........`

It seems like if the permisions work for FileZilla, they should work for commons.net also. Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the serverside everything should be ok. When you can log in with one client the other client should be ok as well.

I cannot tell however if the server for example uses something like passive mode and your library doesn't support that feature.

Are you sure that you are connecting to the same port and the server is not using sftp, etc?

Comment: hmmm, I just realized FileZilla is using sftp. The Java library uses FTP. I am guessing this is the problem.